# OpenCV and Tesseract Crashing on certain computers

Tags: c++, opencv, tesseract

```
std::string outText, imPath = "image.jpeg";
cv::Mat im = cv::imread(imPath, cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);      
cv::bitwise_not(im, im);

tesseract::TessBaseAPI* ocr = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
ocr->Init(NULL, "eng", tesseract::OEM_DEFAULT)
ocr->SetImage(im.data, im.cols, im.rows, 1, im.step);
outText = std::string(ocr->GetUTF8Text());
ocr->End();
```

This code runs fine on a majority of user's computers, but crashes on some computers (especially older computers).

One user reported that it works fine on a computer with a quad-core processor but fails on any computer with a dual-core process. So this is what I think might be a possible issue.

Is there something in opencv or tesseract that can used to prevent the crashes?

The program crashes here:

```
outText = std::string(ocr->GetUTF8Text());
```

But it has no exception. It's just a pure appcrash.

Comment: you need to determine *how* this crashes. at the very least load a coredump into the debugger and investigate. there is no way to advise before you've figured out what has actually happened.

Comment: What do you mean by crashing ? You not get anyt output of error snippet or warning ? Did you try to debug your code ?

Comment: As far as I know, it works for the majority of people no problem. It works perfectly fine for me. I was thinking if there was anything in opencv or tesseract that handles possible issues on lower end systems.

Comment: The issue seems to crash here: string outText = string(ocr->GetUTF8Text());